# why does my browser download files again even tho it's already cached?(cache storage, http)

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm running website these days and play video on there. for playing video on website, I uploaded my video file on web server and embed it with video tag. However, Playing video just like that, use a lot of data. So I wanted to store videos in cache storage.So I extended a range of cache storage store on browser to 4GB like below picture(it's chrome setting)[image: it's chrome setting]

and extended expired date of cache memory with meta tag and header function both(just in case)

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: max-age=31536000"); // HTTP/1.0
?>
```

and

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=31536000">
</head>
```

it seems work fine at first because network console said it's disk cached when I reload my page and do not download again. However Sometimes it download same videos even tho console said it's already disk cached(and it's not a just small header data but a whole video)

below is browser console when it download videos again[image]

I'm learning coding recently, tbh not familiar with this header transfer things.So without further ado, What I'm curious is this. is there any way to prevent redownload video when it's already cached? or is there any other good way to reduce data usage of video on web?
Thx for reading my clumsy question. your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Browser reloads don't necessarily respect the cache (since the point of a browser reload is often to fix something broken about a page). So that's not a good way to test this. Also, you can look at the response headers directly in the developer tools to see if your `Cache-Control` header is set.

Comment: oh yes true I checked my header set in my php file and I could see Cache-control in it. but I couldn't see cache-control in video file. do you know how to set cache-control on video, img etc I just googled it and it says I need nginx however  I can't install another web server at the moment :/

Comment: oh, never mind it was a silly question. I found a way to set cache-control of media file, appreciate your help a lot!!